# If an API is like a restaurant waiter, what exactly are the Application, Programming, Interface?

Tags: api

An API is often analogized to [a waiter in the restaurant](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/gp1nra/apis_explain_like_im_5/frjubhk/) but the analogy stops here fruitlessly. To assist me to understand this analogy, I want to match each of the words in "API" to something about the restaurant waiter, like body parts or waiter's functions. Thus what exactly is the Application? Programming? Interface?

[image]

[Source of picture](https://mvam.org/2018/08/27/waiter-please/). [Understanding APIs: What They Are Why They Matter Rigor](https://rigor.com/blog/what-is-an-api-a-brief-intro/)

> Think of an API as a waiter at a restaurant:
>
> [image: An API is like a waiter]
>
> [image: An API is like a waiter]
>
> At a restaurant, you are handed a menu of items that you can order. You can then add specific instructions about how you want those items prepared.
>
> Once you’ve made your decisions, you give your order to the waiter, saying, “I want the filet mignon, medium-rare, with a side of creamed spinach and a fully-loaded baked potato with no chives.”
>
> The waiter writes down your order and delivers it to the kitchen team, who prepares your meal to your exact specifications.
>
> Once your meal is prepared, the waiter picks it up from the kitchen and serves it to you at your table. You review it to make sure that you have received everything you requested – and then you eat.
>
> The waiter’s role in this scenario closely mirrors the role of an API in the delivery of data on the modern web. Like a waiter, an API:
>
> 1. **Receives a set of instructions** (a request) from a source (such as an application or engineer)
> 2. **Takes that request to the database**
> 3. **Fetches the requested data or facilitates a set of actions**
> 4. **Returns a response to the source**

Comment: I downvoted the question. Application programming interface is an expression, the words should not be taken separately. An API is an interface used to program an application.

Comment: Application is the restaurant (or, rather, the kitchen). Programming is you giving instructions and responding to questions, etc. It's you, the guest, interacting with the restaurant - telling them what you want to eat or drink, how you want the food to be prepared. The waiter is the interface - it's your only way to influence what happens in the kitchen; you can't just barge in and give the orders, or cook the meal yourself. You have to go through the waiter, who acts as a mediator, in-between person (an inter-face), and there's an established way to do it (you look at the menu, etc.)

Comment: This analogy is way off the mark since it's confusing the function of a service with the concept of an API (it looks as the author of that article somewhat misunderstands the term).    An API doesn't receive a set of instructions (indeed an API doesn't have any behaviour at all), the API *is* the set of instructions as well as the response(s).    A service would receive a set of instructions and do all the database handling/actions, as well as return the response;  a service is not an API;  an API is a set of instructions that an external application uses to communicate with that service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with analogies is that they tend to break as soon as you try to look beneath the surface and that is also the case with the waiter analogy. There simply isn't a correspondence between the constituent words of the term "API" and parts of a physical waiter in a restaurant.

To analyze what API stands for, it is best to start with the last word: Interface

> noun
>
> 1. a surface regarded as the common boundary of two bodies, spaces, or phases.
> 2. the facts, problems, considerations, theories, practices, etc., shared by two or more disciplines, procedures, or fields of study:
>    *the interface between chemistry and physics*.
> 3. a common boundary or interconnection between systems, equipment, concepts, or human beings.
> 4. communication or interaction:
>    *Interface between the parent company and its subsidiaries has never been better*.
> 5. a thing or circumstance that enables separate and sometimes incompatible elements to coordinate effectively:
>    *The organization serves as an interface between the state government and the public*.
> 6. computer hardware or software designed to communicate information between hardware devices, between software programs, between devices and programs, or between a device and a user.
>
> <sub>Source: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interface</sub>

The common trend here is that an interface is a boundary between two things and that is also how it is used in the term API. An API is a boundary between a piece of software and the outside world.

A piece of software can have multiple kinds of boundaries or interfaces and that is where the Application and Programmer come into play.

One kind of interface that you probably have seen already a number of times is the User Interface. That interface is aimed at the end-user of a piece of software and has nowadays often a graphical nature. The page that I am using to write this answer is part of the User Interface of the Stack Exchange system. as is the page you are looking at when reading the answer.

An API is a different kind of interface that is intended to be used by other software (applications) and that must be understood by the programmers writing that other software. And API can take may forms, ranging from a set of functions or classes that the users of a library can invoke to a set of commands that can be sent over a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an analogy.. this one might be better -

> Think of an API like a menu in a restaurant. The menu provides a list of dishes you can order, along with a description of each dish. When you specify what menu items you want, the restaurant’s kitchen does the work and provides you with some finished dishes. You don’t know exactly how the restaurant prepares that food, and you don’t really need to.

> Similarly, an API lists a bunch of operations that developers can use, along with a description of what they do. The developer doesn’t necessarily need to know how, for example, an operating system builds and presents a “Save As” dialog box. They just need to know that it’s available for use in their app.

So don't try to associate API with just REST API request with database in web involved. API can be interface between any two systems like an application using Operating system's print API to show Print window.

Reference from - https://www.howtogeek.com/343877/what-is-an-api/